# Access deployed file on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my app using aws elastic beanstalk and want to access those file on the instance. Is there anyway to do that ? I am able to login to my instance. 
I used find command to trace the file location but could not find it. 
If yes, what is the path where all deployed class files will be present ?

Comment: Hey, what stack (Java, Node.js, Docker, etc.) have you used?

Comment: I am using java mainly. However the files that are present in my application are jsp, html, js, css, images as well.